# SKProduct localizedTitle always English

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have in app purchase in my app. I am testing a Japanase language device with a test account that is in the Japan store. I have both English and Japanese in app purchase titles and descriptions.

No matter what I do the localizedTitle and localizedDescription of SKProduct always come back in English.

What am I doing wrong?

My iPad 3 was originally setup in the United States store with English as the language, but I signed out of my store account and went through the normal process in the app to sign in with a Japan test iTunes account. The language of the device is currently Japanese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to go through the create new account flow from the store menu item in the Settings app. I didn't actually create an account, but just going through a couple of screens was enough to set the device to Japan store mode.

Comment: I change the store and the price property is working. However, localizedTitle and localizedDescription properties are not.